# Find maximum cost path in a directed graph

Tags: python, graph, igraph

Is there a good solution to find the maximum cost path in a directed graph from source to destination? I tried to use "all_simple_paths" method from netwrkx and then find the maximum cost path from retrieved paths. However, the method itself did not scale and not even finish due to a large number of node ~ 700 and ~ 600 edges. Any suggestion?
I looked at this solution but did not know how to come up with the distance method mentioned in relax. 
https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/78154/maximum-weighted-paths-in-a-dag

Note: my graph has already a start and end node and all edges are **out** in start node and **in** in the end node

Comment: Perhaps you could use `shortest_path` from networkx with negative weights?

Comment: You mean to negate all weights and then use the shortest_path method? is that going to give the maximum cost path?

Comment: Longest path is NP hard, so I think you're out of luck re the optimum answer. You might get an approximation in polynomial time with a randomized or greedy algorithm.

Comment: @practitioner nevermind, the networkx implementation only accepts non-negative weights. Makes sense in light of Gene's comment.

Comment: this method from networkx "bellman_ford_predecessor_and_distance" can handle negative weights and find the shortest path, according to the docs.

Comment: @practitioner [this](https://web.stanford.edu/class/archive/cs/cs161/cs161.1168/lecture14.pdf) reference suggests that Bellman-Ford only computes correct ways if there are no negative cycles. It does seem like you are out of luck for the exact solution.

Comment: " if there are no negative cycles " I am not sure I get this. My graph guarantees there is no cycle.